# How to load external text file in JavaScript Word API?

Tags: javascript, ms-word

I'm trying to load text file to parse it and insert into ms-document, but standard JavaScript methods doesn't seem to work.

I've tried

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/foo.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
```

and tried accessing by

```
document.getElementById("file-id").files[0]
```

but HTMLElement doesn't have 'files' property in Word API

Comment: Please show the code of what you have tried. Read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try the FileReader https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 0):

I recommended using `fetch()` to load all files like `.txt` in JavaScript.

For text:

```
fetch('foo.txt').then(x => x.text()).then(y => alert(y));
```

For JSON:

```
fetch('foo.txt').then(x => x.json()).then(y => alert(y));
```

For images:

```
fetch('me.jpg').then(x => x.blob()).then(y => document.getElementById('demo').src = URL.createObjectURL(y));
```